# Finding an element in a bash array and printing the row out

Tags: arrays, bash, csv, awk

I have this as a csv file:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4
wow,this,is,awesomeee
we,are,going,to
what,is,the,name
```

This is by script:

```
names=($(awk < example_list.csv -F, '{print $2}'))
lines=($(awk < example_list.csv -F, '{print $0 $1 $2 $3 }'))

for i in "${names[@]}"
do
        if [ ${names[i]}=="is" ]
        then
                echo ${lines[i]}
        fi
done
```

My goal is to find a match in the third column (index 2) and print the whole row out based on that matching index.

In this case:

I save the whole third column to an array (`names`)

I save all columns and rows to a second array (`lines`)

I then iterate through array `names`, looking for a matching word "is"

If it is found, I print out the whole row from array `list` based on that matching index.

Unfortunately, this does not work. All this prints out is:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4Column1Column2Column3
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4Column1Column2Column3
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4Column1Column2Column3
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4Column1Column2Column3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making it too complicated, you can just use this `awk` to print full record when 3rd field is `"is"`:

```
awk -F, '$3=="is"' file
wow,this,is,awesomeee
```

Comment: Oh.. well. That's embarrassing.. This works. Thanks!